# Auth0 Login Approaches for Standalone watchOS App

Tags: ios, swift, auth0, apple-watch, watchos

in the process of migrating mobile offerings from an in-house authentication system to auth0.  one reason is adding SSO functionality, which the in-house system does not support.

currently, have an iPhone app as well as a related standalone watchOS app.  this implementation allows the user to login via the iPhone app, whereby auth tokens are shared with the watchOS app.  in addition, since the watchOS app is standalone (and the iPhone may not be available) the user has the alternative of logging in on the watch with same username and password credentials.

the iPhone app will migrate to auth0's Universal Login, limited to username / password or SSO -- i.e., no social login or biometrics.  the expectation is these auth tokens will be shared with the watch app, like in the existing implementation.

in the case of standalone watch app, however, trying to determine what login approaches are available:

- is there an equivalent to Universal Login for watchOS -- my understanding is there is not?
- are there alternatives to username / password entry, which is clunky on the watch -- had seen mention of OTP assumably via SMS?
- how might SSO login be supported in standalone mode?

Comment: Your first problem is that if you are using SSO then you have no control over the actual authentication method; the identity provider controls all of that and you just get a token at the end, so probably there is no viable solution for the watch because there is no web view available. For the username/password you could look into password less where the user enters their email and a passcode is emailed to them, which they then enter. Is the app truly stand alone, in that the user may *never* use the companion app or is it just functional  without the phone?

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the reply.  that is valid point about SSO.  in my case, support for SSO login on watchOS could be consider optional; I am just trying to consider all use cases. for non-SSO login, i will dig deeper into passwordless, though SMS on watch is preferable to email.  finally, the app is stand alone, but the user will always have used the app, and the app will be the primary login modality.

Comment: Sms is not typically considered secure enough for passwordless login, particularly in the US where the carriers seem to have an appalling record of allowing unauthorised SIM swaps. The theory behind using email is that access to the email account is authenticated via some reasonably secure method.